# Show the number of quantity items in the cart Badge

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

When I add the same item to the cart, the quantity on the cart badge does not increase. How can I increase the number, even when adding the same product. It only changes when I add a different product.

**Cart provider**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.price,
  });
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};

  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  int get itemCount {
    return _items.length;
  }
```

**Badge**

```
Consumer<Cart>(
                      builder: (_, cart, ch) => Badge(
                        child: ch!,
                        value: cart.itemCount.toString(),
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
```

Comment: can you show the code where you "add' to your cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can add this getter to your Cart class.

```dart
int get totalItems {
  return items.values.fold<int>(0, (currentValue, cartItem) {
    return currentValue += cartItem.quantity;
  });
}
```

> Or you can add one more field in your `Cart` class as `itemCount`. In that case, you have to update the value of `itemCount` property every time adding something to the `cart`.

Also, check my [github repo](https://github.com/Kishan-Dhankecha/vegcart) for help.